The conditional in 'If you'd have read the actual BIS papers, they name Ripple and Stellar directly.'
If I understand it correctly,  'If you'd have read the actual BIS papers, they name Ripple and Stellar directly.' means  'If you would have read the actual BIS papers, you would have seen that they name Ripple and Stellar directly.'
Would  re-writing the original sentence as 'If you'd read the actual BIS papers, they name Ripple and Stellar directly.' change the meaning? If so, how?
The sentence 'mBridge has Ripple written all over it.  If you'd have read the actual BIS papers, they name Ripple and Stellar directly.' is a comment to the Youtube video titled 'BRICS New Currency Could CRASH The US Dollar?! This Is How!'.

I would use If you had read. To my mind, the more complicated tense is unnecessary.

"If you'd read" is ambiguous in writing, as it could be "would read" or "had read", differing in pronunciation of "read". But the original doesn't sound very good and I'm not sure I'd recommend it.
